# arabic encode - django

Tags: python, django, encoding

I am doing

```
>>> s = unicode('أي كلمة من كلمات القاموس تصفك أفضل ما يمكن؟')
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s = u"أي كلمة من كلمات القاموس تصفك أفضل ما يمكن؟"
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s = "أي كلمة من كلمات القاموس تصفك أفضل ما يمكن؟".encode('utf-8')
Unsupported characters in input

>>> s = "أي كلمة من كلمات القاموس تصفك أفضل ما يمكن؟"
Unsupported characters in input
```

but none of them is working. what am I doing wrong?

I have django 1.6 and python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the top of your code. It works for my Hebrew, Arabic, and technically for any other language.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Or alternatively, you can print it as a raw string. So:

```
s = r"أي كلمة من كلمات القاموس تصفك أفضل ما يمكن؟"
print s
```

Comment: what is the difference between ``# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`` and ``#!-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`` ?

Comment: my bad you are correct there is not meant to be an exclamation point i mixed it up with the python shebang. I apologize. There is only #-\*- coding: utf-8 -*- sometimes you might see this though #-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-