# Django mysql arabic encoding

Tags: mysql, django, encoding, arabic

I've a django app with a mysql database. We are trying to launch the Arabic version of the website. The current language is English. For some reason when I write something in Arabic through the admin panel and click save, it shows ???? instead of the Arabic word i wrote. I've no idea how to fix it.

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759717/arabic-encode-django) and added `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to my admin.py, models.py and views.py files. It didn't work

I also added these to my.conf mysql file to change the character set. It didn't work either.

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
init_connect='set collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;'
```

Comment: And what you have in the DB? Is there correct strings in Arabic or broken encoding?

Comment: When i go through the shell and try to print them. It shows ???

Comment: Did you checked encoding of your database and your tables?

Comment: @Paul How do i check that?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049728/how-do-i-see-what-character-set-a-mysql-database-table-column-is

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked encoding of your database and your tables?
If they are not in utf-8, you might try to convert it.

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE `db_table_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

(code is from here: [Save Data in Arabic in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859018/save-data-in-arabic-in-mysql-database))

Comment: How dod i run sql commands in django? Sorry but I'm very new to this.

Comment: None of those `ALTERs` are likely to impact the problem.  They change the defaults, not the actual encoding.

Answer (score 1):

What probably happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can formulate an `ALTER` to fix the columns.

Django needs `client_encoding: 'UTF8'`; sorry, I don't know where that goes.